# ios- appropriate way to do background process

Tags: ios, uiwebview, notifications

I've gotten lost. I'm a new IOS developer coming from Android and I'm in desperate need of some clarification. I have an app which does some checks, namely, it makes a UIWebView, loads a webpage, downloads the source and extracts some numbers I need from it. Now what I want to do is, the app has to do this in the background and notify the user when there is a change in numbers. Now in Android I just used a `BroadcastReceiver`, doing the check, and sending a notification whenever there was a change. I've read about `UILocalNotification` but I'm not sure how to achieve the same on IOS as I have on Android. I have to fire some code first, to then determine whether to fire a Notification. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically don't download this in a `UIWebView`, but with an [`NSURLConnection`](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/) or [`NSURLSession`](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial). After the download is complete, you need a `UILocalNotification` indeed.

Comment: So it is possible with UILocalNotification to first do the check and to then decide whether to fire the notification to the user?

Comment: I'd only create the UILocalNotification after the results of the download are known, but it will only be fired when you call [`presentLocalNotificationNow:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/presentLocalNotificationNow:)

Comment: But then I still need something to do the checks with in the background, is this possible with UILocalNotification?

Comment: You can fire `UILocalNotification`s from the background, yes.

Comment: Thank you very much, kind sir.